# Adding click event handlers to React components that render after initial page render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I currently have the below function which is injected into every page.

```js
componentDidMount(){
    const gaElements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-action]")
    gaElements.forEach(el => {  
        el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        gtag.event({ action: el.getAttribute("data-action") , category: el.getAttribute("data-category"), label: el.getAttribute("data-label"), value: el.getAttribute("data-value") })
        })
    })
}
```

This adds a click-event handler to all elements that have the `data-action` attribute.
This works well for all elements that are on the page during initial render, however, some elements are being generated after the initial render as I'm fetching from an API and rendering the components as I receive the data.

How would I go about adding the same click-event handler to all components regardless of when they're rendered?

Would something like componentDidUpdate work?

Comment: Yours is a non-React approach; you need to put all possible elements in your `render()` function's JSX and render them conditionally, then use the `onClick` attribute in the JSX code to assign click handlers to them.

Comment: Ok, so you're injecting a React app into an HTML document. If the elements are inserted outside, simply add the event listeners after inserting them. If they are part of the React app, we're back at `onClick` in JSX in `render()`. Bottom line is that you need to be more specific about how exactly this is supposed to work.

Comment: Essentially, yes. How would I go about adding the event listener once more components are rendered?
I could place a ternery operator on the return of the pages that make api requests so that they're only rendered once the data is available, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Again: if the new elements are part of your React app, you're supposed to use the `onClick` attribute. I edited my comment, so maybe you saw an older version. You shouldn't use `addEventListener` in React because that's not how React works.

Comment: Ok cool I'll make that change, thank you

Answer (score 0):

As an example (in a class component)

```
state = {
  elements: [] // your elements
}

handleClick = (e, value) => {
 console.log'e, value)
}

renderEl = (props) => { // this work too: renderEl = ({key, handleClick, text})
   return (
     <li key={props.key} onClick={(e) => props.handleClick(e, someValue)}>{props.text}</li>
   )
}

render() {
   const { elements }= this.state //this way this.setState will trigger render when you will add or remove elements
   return(
     <ul>
       {elements.map(el, idx => {
          return renderEl({handleClick:this.handleClick, text:'text', key:idx})
       }
     </ul>
   )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but while this will work it would require me to add this onto every single element or list of elements manually. I suppose my question wasn't very clear, I have updated it.

My code is applied to all pages in my application. What I liked was that I didn't have to manually add it to every element

Comment: Because I want to learn to, and I receive a -1, should someone, in fact the guy who put me (-1), can explain to me his reason ?